# find papers that are based on another paper

Tags: publications

There is a paper on my field that I like very much(machine vision). I have implemented the solution it proposes and it works well (not flawless obviously). 
However this paper was published in 1991. 
Is there a way that I can search relevant and more recent papers *that use this paper as its basis*??  -I mean it is rather easy to the opposite, just check the references, but how about the other way?)

(Talking more specialized jargon, this papers deals with one (of many) ways to implement a machine vision operation. I like this method rather than others, and I would like to find papers that propose improvements to this method-rather than go to other direction)

Comment: Do you mean finding papers that cite this one? Go to google scholar and search for this paper, hit the "cited by" button below the entry and you'll see all papers that cited this one.

Answer (score 3):

Google Scholar is a possibility. Another possibility is Web of Science (WoS), if you have access to it. It allows you to access a list of all papers citing the one you are interested in via '**Times Cited**' (click on the number). Of course only WoS-indexed sources will be included. On the resulting list you can perform all refinement and sorting actions that WoS allows.

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately, you can use Google Scholar to search for an article and all subsequent articles **which cite it.** You only need to click the blue link which says "Cited by XXX" to find the list from the search results of your Google Scholar query.

Comment: And if you end up with a very large number of results, note that you can check the "Search within citing articles" box and then run a further Google search of the results.

Comment: And this is so much easier than the old-fashioned method -- the bound paper citation index in its many volumes.